How do split-phase utility meter accurately measure energy without a neutral connection?
Most residential electrical smart meters in the US have 4 terminals: in/out for each phase. They do not have a neutral or ground connection, although there are also 5-jaw meter sockets with a neutral connection, but these are very rare.
This means the only information they have access to is the current on each phase, and the voltage between them.
Without knowing neutral-phase voltage, how can they accurately measure total energy? Do they assume the transformer feeding is perfectly balanced with exactly the same voltage between each phase and neutral (this seems like a terrible assumption, it is common to see one phase 5V lower than the other!), or is there some clever trick to accurately measure total energy on a split-phase system without knowing neutral voltage?

Current on the neutral is exactly the difference between the two phase currents. There's no new information there.

@PeteBecker agreed that neutral current plus both phase currents is 0, so you can derive neutral current. But if one phase is 110V, and the other is 130V, you need to know the voltage of each phase relative to neutral to calculate total power accurately. A 1A load on the first phase is 110W, but on the other phase it's 130W. How can you figure that out simply from phase currents and the voltage between the phases? Or does the meter just assume the neutral voltage is exactly halfway between the phase-to-phase voltage?

A 1 A load is connected to one phase and neutral, but any high power load is to both phases without a neutral connection.
So if one phase is 110V, and the other is 130V, the energy consumed by a low power load is measured with a small error. If both phases are 100 V instead of 120 V, the assumption of the neutral voltage exactly halfway between the phase-to-phase voltage is corrrect.
But the energy used by a high power load is calculated from a precise measurement of voltage and current.
